# How to install a .sh script?

Tags: python, shell

I have written a script named "installcms.sh" and i placed it /root

This is my script

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python-imaging >> installcms.log > 2>&1


easy_install pip >> installcms.log > 2>&1

pip install django django-cms south django-appmedia >> installcms.log > 2>&1

django-admin.py startproject djangocmsproject >> installcms.log > 2>&1

cd djangocmsproject

rm settings.py

rm urls.py

cp /root/settings.py settings.py >> installcms.log > 2>&1

cp /root/urls.py urls.py >> installcms.log > 2>&1

mkdir templates

cd templates

cp /root/example.html example.html >> installcms.log > 2>&1

cd ..

python manage.py syncdb --all >> installcms.log > 2>&1

python manage.py migrate --fake >> installcms.log > 2>&1

python manage.py runserver >> installcms.log > 2>&1
```

---

When i try to execute my script using the command "/root/installcms.sh"

I am getting this error

```
****/root/installcms.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `2'**

**/root/installcms.sh: line 2: `apt-get install python-setuptools python-imaging >> installcms.log > 2>&1'****
```

Comment: Replace all of those `> 2>&1`s with `2>&1`.

Comment: `... >> foo.log 2>&1` (no extra >)

Comment: Looks like you should be creating a collection of Debian packages, not an ad-hoc security and maintainability sinkhole of a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error messages your script is incorrect.

The following redirection is not valid: `>> installcms.log > 2>&1`

It should be: `>> installcms.log 2>&1`

You can check http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html for further explanations on how redirection works in bash

(i assumed your default shell is bash, but redirection in other shells should be the same)

Comment: Thanks, it works. but now i am getting this error: ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: You can choose an answer as valid so that your question doesn't appear as 'Unanswered' any more. Thanks.

Comment: @Mathi those errors are coming from the script itself. Since the initial question was about crontab (and incorrectly tagged as 'python' by the way), you should probably open a new question regarding the script itself, in order not to confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
>> installcms.log > 2>&1
```

Should be:

```
>> installcms.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but now i am getting this error: ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Comment: @Mathi: Glad you got the script running. This error comes from one of the programs that the script runs. I cannot tell which. YOu'll have to troubleshoot this yourself.